# Delete row of mySQL table from iOS app

Tags: ios, mysql, uitableview

I'm currently working on an iOS app that takes information from a mySQL database and outputs it to JSON which in turn is displayed in a UITableView. I would like to be able to delete a row of the UITableView, which would also delete the corresponding row in the database. I know I need to use this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_wordsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.editTableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm not sure how it works, I know I'll have to use a PHP script in order for the row to be deleted from the database. What needs to be done on the iOS side? Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> What needs to be done on the iOS side?

This is a pretty broad question. You have to be more specific what you need help with.

Generally speaking this is what needs to be done which I am sure you already knew.

- Delete the record from your array and reload the table. I see you have already done that.
- I am assuming you are storing that array locally somewhere (NSUserDefaults, plist etc), otherwise the user will need to get latest data from your server on every app launch and make sure the delete row doesn't reappear
- You need to make a Async call to your php on your server
- You would need to pass in values like what info has the user decided to delete and then execute that delete in the database

If you need code samples then google it my man.

Comment: Thanks. The array is stored through a JSON response actually. I've already tried to look up code samples, that's why I posted it on here

Comment: What I need to do is delete the JSON object by calling a php script and then reloading the table view... any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same, kinda, using a mySQL database to save my data and using arrays to access the tables on the iOS level. What I do for inserting, updating and deleting records from the database is something like this:

### Using mySQL on a iOS Level ##

1. **mySQL to iOS level:** first is to create a method, or inline function, somewhere that is accessible anywhere in the app; inside a singleton for an example. This method will return an array that contains **one record** by passing a `sqlite3_statement` in the parameter list. This method looks something like:

**example**

```
/**
* From the parameter list, an array is produced in Entry format
* @param [in] statement incoming value from previous call sqlite3_step(..) == SQLITE_ROW
* @return NSArray: Entry format
*/
static inline NSMutableArray * SQLStatementRowIntoEntryEntry( sqlite3_stmt *statement) { 
...
return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: stringSubject, date dateCreated, stringBody, emotion, weatherCondition, temperature isBookmarked, [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_int( statement, SQL_ENTRIES_id)], @"id", nil], nil];

};
```

How I save id keys from the mySQL record is put it in a dictionary as the last object, so it kinda stays out of the way while I'm using the array on the iOS level. But then is there ready whenever I want to update or delete this record from the database.

2. **Updating and Deleting Records from iOS level:** so because the id was saved in the array for each record this makes it remarkably easy to update or delete records in the database. In your query you'd have something like:

   ```
   NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE Entries SET subject = \"%@\", date = \"%@\", dateCreated = \"%@\", body = \"%@\", emotion = %d, weatherCondition = %d, temperature = %d, isBookmarked = %d, diaryID = %d where id = %d;", [[arrayEntry objectEntry_subject] stringByReformatingForSQLQuries], [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [arrayEntry objectEntry_date]], [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [arrayEntry objectEntry_dateCreated]], [[arrayEntry objectEntry_body] stringByReformatingForSQLQuries], [arrayEntry objectEntry_emotion], [arrayEntry objectEntry_weatherCondition], [arrayEntry objectEntry_temperature], [arrayEntry objectEntry_isBookmarked], [[[[[arrayEntry optionsDictionary] objectForKey: @"diary"] optionsDictionary] objectForKey: @"id"] intValue], [[[arrayEntry lastObject] objectForKey: @"id"] intValue]];
   ```

What you want is the  `[[[arrayEntry lastObject] objectForKey: @"id"] intValue]` to take place of `.. where id = %d;` to either update or delete a record.

I hope this helps and do ask for any questions, I copied and pasted code from my project m

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Database query string to your php Script.

> NSString *sqlquery = [NSSring sringwithFormate : @"DELETE FROM tabel_name WHERE tabel_id='your_tabel_row_id'"];

In this tabel_id is the your database row id which is you want to delete and your_tabel_row_id is the identifier which help to you to delete the record from the database.